# How to comply with Apache License V2.0 when self-hosting fonts

Tags: web-hosting, legal, fonts, licenses

I am considering self-hosting a font licensed under the [Apache License Version 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) for a commercial progressive web app. My goal is to ensure full compliance with the license, and I have a few specific questions:

1. Section 4 of the Apache License Version 2.0 requires me to 'give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License'. If I hosted the .woff files on my website, how could I effectively and compliantly provide users access to the license text as required by the Apache License?
2. Section 4 also states one 'must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating that You changed the files'. If I obtained the font in .ttf format and converted it to .woff format, would I need to add a notice? If so, how?

Comment: I think these are more legal questions that could be answered by the Apache foundation, but let's see if someone can help here.  An answer may be useful for others.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The question is really on how to serve the font compliantly, looking for technical solutions that are fully compliant with a strict interpretation of the license. Would, for example, base64 encoding the font, embedding it in the css directly, and also placing the license and a note regarding the modifications there as comment, fully comply with the license requirements?

Answer (score 1):

When you download the font in order to self host it. There should be license information.

For Fonts on Google when you select the font an about and license is given as an option. Which confirms the license and the creator of the font.

[image]

Roboto for example is Designed by Christian Robertson and uploaded to https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto and contains the full license.

---

You can of course create your own font and self-host it or purchase a license to use a font that is not otherwise already licensed to be used on the web.

It is often a practice when creating a logo to create a copyrighted font to provide additional legal protection against others using or copying the logo. A Derivative work of a otherwise licensed font is copyrightable to you if you create the new font based on a public domain font or a font where derivative works are allowed, always best to check the license -- in some cases fonts may require derivative works are also (Apache License Version 2.0), always check the license for the specific font.

Comment: Thank you for your response and efforts. However, I am seeking guidance on how to serve a self-hosted font compliantly with Apache V2. Regarding the Roboto font you mentioned, there is a GitHub issue (https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/issues/247) discussing the challenge of self-hosting, which involves redistributing.